# No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I am creating a Build and release pipeline for my .Net core FunctionApp in Azure. I am getting the following error

```
2020-07-13T07:59:10.6443361Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

Below is the yaml file of the pipeline

YAML file

```
# .NET Core Function App to Windows on Azure
# Build a .NET Core function app and deploy it to Azure as a Windows function App.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'f296911a-0481-4fed-ba93-a30ef6a5b0f2'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'srlcustomermanagerapp'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'vs2017-win2016'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CustomerOrderApi'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Release configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Make sure you've set the Build Pipeline as artifact source, and the build do provide the artifacts:

[image]

[image]

2.If the issue persists, try to specify the path via `Browse Package or folder` option:

[image]

[image]

Then you can check if your release can get the required `xx.zip` file via this option. Also you can choose to specify the file path using this option.