# Can't run my build release task on azure release pipeline error Exception: An error occurred while initializing the settings provider named 'MSTest'

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest

I have not been able to resolve this issue, been working on it for over 2 to 3 days. Here is my setup
and what i have done so far.

building release on a on premise agent.
agent has latest version of VS2017 on it
I'm able to run my test on my local computer that also has VS2017 latest updated version on it.
I was able to run test, in both debug/release configuration.

I was also able to run test on this same agent using Vstest.exe command line tool pointing it
to my test dll and my runsettings file.

I've tried to run it using latest installer task as well as disabling installer task and using
latest version of VS Test.

Here is the errors i'm seeing below when i try to run. Some directions on what i need to do with
some steps would be helpful since i cant get this resolved.

Here is the steps in my installer

1. Agent Job
   Agent selection pool - QA 2
   Parallelism - none
   Artifact download - xxxx CI Build Latest
2. Replace tokens in config
3. Visual Studio Test Platform Installer - disabled
4. Visual Studio test
   task vervison 2*
   Select test using - Test Plan
   Test Plan - 94223 - xxxxxxx
   Test Suite - xxxx xxxxxxx; xxxx xxxxxx\test
   test configuration - 83 - Windows 10 / IE 11
   Search folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
   Test results folder -$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults
   Select test platform using - Version
   Test platform version - Latest
   Settings file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_XXXXX CI Build/drop/XXXXX_Automation_Test/bin/Release/XXXXXtest.runsettings
   Collect advanced diagnostic in case of catastrophic failures

2020-07-20T14:09:03.7831149Z ##[error]DiscoveryMessage : An exception occurred while test discoverer 'MSTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: An error occurred while initializing the settings provider named 'MSTest'. Error: The test settings file E:\xxxxx_xxxx\x7\a\xxxxxxxxxxx.testsettings, specified in the MSTestAdapter settings, is not available. Either access to the file is denied or the file does not exist. Ensure that the test settings file is available and try again.

##[error]ExecutionAndPublish.Run : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.

##[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.

Running without installer
##[error]DiscoveryMessage : An exception occurred while test discoverer 'MSTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: An error occurred while initializing the settings provider named 'MSTest'. Error: The test settings file E:\xxx_xxxxx\x7\a\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.testsettings, specified in the MSTestAdapter settings, is not available. Either access to the file is denied or the file does not exist. Ensure that the test settings file is available and try again.
and stating vs version

Comment: Can you post the details about what you have configured for the assemblies and the runsettings on the test task step.  Does that resolve to the exact path you are using when running locally?  Are you testing with the same account when testing local that the agent service is running as?

Comment: As for the VS test task, could you please share the details about how you define it, so that we can check for you.

Comment: hi @LanceLi-MSFT what kind of details do you need. I can post what i have on here and you can let me know if i'm missing something

Comment: The details about how you configure the release pipeline, how you define the vstest task.  Check example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871810/no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-d-a-r1-a-zipbr-check-if-the-pac/62889480#62889480). And I answered your another similar question  just know, please check that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i formulate file path for testsettings on the Runsettings file parameter <SettingsFile>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018328/how-do-i-formulate-file-path-for-testsettings-on-the-runsettings-file-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

> I was also able to run test on this same agent using Vstest.exe
> command line tool pointing it to my test dll and my runsettings file.

As a workaround you can run vstest command via [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line), this should work since you can run tests in command-line.

If the issue persists, you can add an [Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) which installs `latestStable` version for you.