# How do i formulate file path for testsettings on the Runsettings file parameter <SettingsFile>

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Whats the proper way to form relative file path/ or file path for the runsettings parameter

```
<SettingsFile>xxxxxAutomation.testsettings</SettingsFile>
```

In my local environment this works but when i push it to build release agents it fails since
its looking for the file in a different directory which is my release folder
but instead its looking for this file in what appears to be in a folder directory.

This is the directory its looking at E:\Agent_work\r10\a\xxxxxxxxx.testsettings,

here is my current way i have it set

```
<SettingsFile>xxxxxAutomation.testsettings</SettingsFile>
```

here is the error message
Error: The test settings file E:\Agent_work\r10\a\xxxxxxxxxx.testsettings, specified in the MSTestAdapter settings, is not available. Either access to the file is denied or the file does not exist. Ensure that the test settings file is available and try again.

instead of
E:\Agent_work\r10\a_XXXXX CI Build\drop\XXXXX_Automation_Test\bin\Release\xxxxxxxxx.testsettings

There is no documentation that states how to formulate the file path on msdn and didn't see
anything online.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? If my answer helps to resolve your issue, would you mind accepting it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can add a [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the missing file from  `.../bin/release` folder(Use the browse option) to default working directory:

[image]

I suggest you resolve this issue via modifying your pipeline instead of settings file, so that you can also work well locally with the unchanged runsettings file.

In addition: `Clean Target Folder` input should be disabled(unchecked) cause our target folder is the default working folder. Deleting all files in that folder would cause unexpected issues.

Comment: The second option worked for me.  I will also state that if your having issues with the copy files task. I had clean target folder checked which kept failing because they were any files in the folder to began with so i wouldn't find any files and the task would blow up. Once i unchecked it it worked like a charm.

Comment: @skinnyWill Answer updated, would you mind [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that more members with similar issue may benefit from that. And we can archive it for you then, thx!